# Difference iterating with tp_iternext or PyIter_Next

Tags: python, python-c-api

If I write a C function that does something with an iterable then I create an Iterator first and then loop over it.

```
iterator = PyObject_GetIter(sequence);
if (iterator == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}
while (( item = PyIter_Next(iterator) )) {
    ...
}
```

This works fine but I've also seen some functions using `tp_iternext`:

```
iterator = PyObject_GetIter(sequence); // ....

iternext = *Py_TYPE(iterator)->tp_iternext;
while (( item = iternext(iterator) )) {
    ...
}
```

the second approach seems faster (I have only one data point: my Windows computer and my msvc compiler).

Is it just coincidence that the `iternext` approach is faster and is there any significant difference between these two?

Links to the python documentation of both:
[PyIter_Next](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/iter.html#c.PyIter_Next), 
[tp_iternext](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_iternext)
I have read them but to me it's not clear when and why one should be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code for `PyIter_Next`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/abstract.c#l3145) shows that it simply retrieves the `tp_iternext` slot and calls it **and clears a `StopIteration` exception that may or may not have occurred**.

If you use `tp_iternext` explicitly you have to check for this `StopIteration` when exhausting the iterator.

---

By the way: the documentation of `tp_iternext` also says:

> **`iternextfunc PyTypeObject.tp_iternext`**
>
> An optional pointer to a function that returns the next item in an iterator. When the iterator is exhausted, it must return `NULL`; **a
>   `StopIteration` exception may or may not be set.** When another error
>   occurs, it must return `NULL` too. Its presence signals that the
>   instances of this type are iterators.

While there is no such mention in `PyIter_Next`'s documentation.

So `PyIter_Next` is the simple *and safe* way of iterating over an iterator. You can use `tp_iternext` but then you have to be careful to not trigger a `StopIteration` exception at the end.